# Ansible: conditional register check

Tags: python, linux, ansible, redhat

I'm creating a playbook to perform an action but there is a condition: only execute my command if the date is older than x days

This is what i've tried to use

with_items: "{{ (my_register | sort(attribute='ctime'))[30:] | list }}"

```
- name: some action
  shell: some command | grep command
  register: my_register
  ignore_errors: True

- name: conditional action
  shell: command
  become: yes
  when: my_register
  with_items: "{{ (my_register | sort(attribute='ctime'))[x days:] | list }}"
```

I expect to check if the information in "my_register" is older than x days.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with a test file. Please check if this is useful for your scenario.
In when condition you can give as below

```
  - name: Test
    stat:
        path: /tmp/test.txt
    register: output
  - name: conditional action
    shell: command
    become: yes
    when: (ansible_date_time.epoch|int - output.stat.ctime|int) < 2592000
```

Note: 2592000 is 30 days in seconds

Comment: Your less than sign should be a greater than sign: when: (ansible_date_time.epoch|int - output.stat.ctime|int) > 2592000